# Авторизация на сайте

Tags: c#, .net, авторизация

Подскажите как сделать авторизацию на сайте [lib.rus.ec](http://lib.rus.ec/user/login) без использования WebBrowser.

```
<h1 class='title'>Учетная запись пользователя</h1><div class="tabs"><ul class="tabs primary">
<li ><a href="/user/register">Зарегистрироваться</a></li>
<li class="active" ><a href="/user">Вход в систему</a></li>
<li ><a href="/user/password">Запросить новый пароль</a></li>
</ul>
</div><form action="/user/login"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="user-login">
<div><div class="form-item" id="edit-name-wrapper">
 <label for="edit-name">Имя пользователя или адрес электронной почты: <span class="form-required" title="Это поле необходимо заполнить.">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" maxlength="60" name="name" id="edit-name" size="60" value="" class="form-text required" />
 <div class="description">Вы можете использовать свой ник или адрес.</div>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-pass-wrapper">
 <label for="edit-pass">Пароль: <span class="form-required" title="Это поле необходимо заполнить.">*</span></label>
 <input type="password" name="pass" id="edit-pass"  maxlength="128"  size="60"  class="form-text required" />
 <div class="description">Большие и маленькие буквы - это разные буквы. Не запутайтесь.</div>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-persistent-login-wrapper">
 <label class="option" for="edit-persistent-login"><input type="checkbox" name="persistent_login" id="edit-persistent-login" value="1"   class="form-checkbox" /> Помнить меня</label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-34ef62ca5ae804bb03c7b6a8d1a44320" value="form-34ef62ca5ae804bb03c7b6a8d1a44320"  />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-user-login" value="user_login"  />
<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Вход в систему"  class="form-submit" />

</div></form>
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону HttpWebRequest. [Вот здесь][1] есть пример кода. Ваша задача - послать POST-запрос на сервер lib.rus.ec, засунув туда в качестве параметров логин и пароль пользователя, затем прочитать ответ сервера


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346

Comment: в .net 4.5 появился удобный System.Net.HttpClient.
для дебага можно использовать fiddler (ним можно посмотреть какие именно данные посылает браузер серверу)